# Partial read a text file with node.js and lodash

Tags: node.js, lodash

I am trying to read a text file using node.js. I know how to read it line by line but i need to read it partially.

There are various sections into the file like ~SECTION A then the data goes for section A,  ~SECTION B then data for section B and son on. I want to read a pirticular section instead of reading the whole file.

What is the best way to do it using node.js

**UPDATE**
I know there is a npm package for lodash. I am thinking to read the whole file line by line and insert each line into and array. Then use lodash to just get the part of that array something like
someMethod(myarray,"~SECTION B","~SECTION C");
So i am looking for a method in lodash that can take start string and end string and get the the data in between as an array ??  Is it possible using lodash ?

Comment: There's no shortcut in reading a flat file. Read it line by line or character by character until you find what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in Node.js, but I am sure there is something like a config parser as `ini` files (if you have a structure like that).

That being said, any way that involves parsing this file with core information in lines, will have to read the whole file.

So if you have the ability to read the file line by line, there is nothing stopping you from writing a parser for that file!

Just iterate over the file, as soon as you hit the section you like, you enable a flag that makes sure that you will be reading the following lines, until you hit another section which disables the flag.

Bonus points for stopping the iteration at the next Section.

You can come up with more efficient strategies if the file follows some constraints like sections being ordered alphabetically.

Comment: This is what i am writing right now, but i was wondering if there is a better solution.

Comment: i assume that you dont have control over the file's structure? otherwise you could use a more supported format. If it comes close to an ini, maybe take a look at this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ini and adjust it to your needs